# Background image for iPhones and iPads of various sizes

Tags: ios, image

I would like to add a background image for iOS and I want the background image to have appropriate resolutions for all tablet and phone versions. What design considerations should I take into account? What resolution should the image be in?

Comment: can you please try checking http://www.fileformat.info/tip/web/imagesize.htm

Comment: By no means this is not an exhaustive list. It doesn't cover newer phones from Apple.

Comment: @SandahAung if my answers helped you, as your latest questions imply, please accept and or upvote my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SASmith I am still trying all the options in your answer. But yes you are helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I would advise to upload an image of what it is you want to achieve in your more recent questions so that people can better understand your needs. I hope you find your answers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This the list of current screen resolutions for the variety of devices: [click for resolutions](http://www.iosres.com)

You could create 10 different images, 5 each for the landscape and portrait views.

Alternatively, you could create 2 or 4 images to cater for the landscape and portrait views and use code to check the devices size to size them appropriately.

The advantages of creating all the right sized images means that you have a precise background that is consistent across all devices, especially if you have logo's in the background as distortion may occur with resizing of images across devices.

Conversely, creating only 2-4 images should reduce memory size as the app downloaded will only be packaged with those background images instead of 10, and if resized correctly, shouldn't look to out of place.

I would test the 2-4 images using simulator, checking the look and performance on all devices you plan to release to. If you aren't happy, either customise your layouts for the images so they stretch to fit appropriately, or, for symmetry across all devices, I would create all the images and package, with an attempt to reduce the size of each image to be perfectly aligned with the device boundaries to reduce memory consumption.

The disadvantage of using 10 different images is the extra code required to fit, and should a new device size come out, you will need to create additional images, which ultimately consumes more memory and requires long term monitoring. It also consumes unnecessary memory if you are using an iPhone 6 and have images for all the other devices.

My advice - weight up whether you really need the background and if so, whether or not resizing just 2 images to fit any device will impact the look of your app.